# Xamarin Forms iOS azure mobile Live Player in iPad. "No Body on Method", NInterpretException

Tags: ios, azure, ipad, azure-mobile-services, xamarin-live-player

Below is my ICloudService
     public class AzureCloudService : ICloudService
    {
        MobileServiceClient client;

```
    public AzureCloudService()
    {
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
        client = new MobileServiceClient("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net");
    }

    public ICloudTable<T> GetTable<T>() where T : TableData
    {
        return new AzureCloudTable<T>(client);
    }
}
```

If i remove the 'client = new' line the application is loaded else it throws below error.

```
Vizualization Error
No body on method
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IApplicationStorage
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.IPlatform::get_ApplicationStorage() (NInterpretException)
```

Comment: What is the exact problem are you facing ?Have you checked [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/azure/)?

Comment: Yes we have consumed the Azure mobile service and it is working fine in Android simulator and devices.
I couldn't able to run my azure mobile app Live Player in iPad, only if i initialise MobileServiceClient.

Answer (score 0):

I've also got the same problem using my iPhone 6 with Live Player.

If I hook Visual Studio up to my Mac and run it through the iPhone simulator in Visual Studio then it works OK, so presumably, it's something wrong with Live Player?